# Magento 2 Invoice Capture Options

Tags: magento2, module, payment-methods, invoice, payment

In Magento 1, you can enable capture options for an invoice by adding

```
protected $_canCapture = true;
```

to **app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\METHODNAME.php**

**In Magento 2, how can this be done?**

I'm trying to do this to the purchase order method so invoices can be created but not marked as paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done **the same way as Magento 1.**

In the payment method class, you can change:

```
protected $_canCapture = false;
```

To:

```
protected $_canCapture = true;
```

Comment: @Ryan feel free to mark your question as answered so it'll benefit for others ;)